# relation error on adding new model class

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have 2 model-classes inside models.py file :

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    generic_certificate = models.ForeignKey(GenericCertificate, related_name='certificates_awarded')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag', related_name='certificates_awarded', null=True, blank=True)


class GenericCertificate(CommonInfo):
    CERTIFICATE_TYPE = (('C', 'system created'),
                        ('U', 'user created'))

    certificate_icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='certificate/icons', default='defaults/certificate.png')
    certificate_type = models.CharField(choices=CERTIFICATE_TYPE, max_length=1, default='C')
    template = models.FileField(upload_to='certificate/generic_templates')
```

They are working fine in django admin , but When I am adding one more model class it starts giving error on hitting Generic certificates option: Included operation : South Migration and  syncdb
**Exception Type:   ProgrammingError
Exception Value:

relation "certificates_genericcertificate" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "certificates_genericcertificate"**

newly added model class in same models.py

```
class PositionCertificate(models.Model):
    rewardee = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = '0,0')
    org_logo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = '0,0')
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = '0,0')
```

How to remove this error ? and why this error is coming ?

Comment: Have you done syncdb, schema migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error
`relation "certificates_genericcertificate" does not exist`
means that "certificates_genericcertificate" relation do not exists in your database.
Please do

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and if you are using South you can use

```
python manage.py migrate
```

try to hit these commands and if it does not help you, drop your tables/database and recreate tables/database by using syncdb.